# TeamCity's git checkout different from local git checkout

Tags: git, teamcity, gitattributes

I'm having a problem with TeamCity (8.1) running on a Windows box and one of our git repositories.
Few files (2 out of 1000s - *.bytes extension, binary) have larger sizes on TeamCity checkout then on developer machines. If I turn off "Convert line-endings to CRLF" sizes for those files are the same, but then rest of the project does not build properly + developer machines do have core.autocrlf=true.

I have also tried setting *.bytes as binary in .gitattributes but this looks like it is being ignored by TeamCity (?).

Does anyone know of a way to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: I'd try to switch to agent side checkout. But for this to work you need to install git on the agent machine. See also: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/VCS+Checkout+Mode

Comment: Yes, that is what I had to do, but this does cause another set of issues, especially for release - when cleaning up requires re-downloading of entire project (few GBs).

Comment: .gitattributes is not supported in jgit used by TeamCity. For more details see this [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-16530).

Comment: Switching for client-side checkout worked for me. I've also set autocrlf = true in my .gitconfig file (just to for sure)